# iterate through div elements

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm a complete beginner in javascript and web scraping using `puppeteer` and I am trying to get the scores of a simple euroleague round in
https://www.euroleague.net/main/results?gamenumber=28&phasetypecode=RS&seasoncode=E2019

[image]

By `inspecting` the score list above I find out that the score list is a `div` element containing other `divs` inside with the stats displayed .

`HTML`  for a single match between 2 teams (there are more divs for matches below this example )

```html
//score list 
    <div class="wp-module wp-module-asidegames wp-module-5lfarqnjesnirthi">
//the data-code increases to "euro_245" ...
    <div class="">      
        <div class="game played" data-code="euro_244" data-date="1583427600000" data-played="1">
            <a href="/main/results/showgame?gamecode=244&amp;seasoncode=E2019" class="game-link">
                <div class="club">
                    <span class="name">Zenit St Petersburg</span> 
                        <span class="score homepts winner">76</span>
                </div>
                <div class="club">
                    <span class="name">Zalgiris Kaunas</span>  
                        <span class="score awaypts ">75</span>
                </div>
                <div class="info">

                        <span class="date">March 5 18:00 CET</span>
                    <span class="live">
                        LIVE <span class="minute"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="final">
                        FINAL
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
       //more teams 
    </div>
        
</div>
```

What I want is to iterate through the outer div element and get the teams playing and the score of each match and store them in a json file . However since I am a complete beginner I do not understand how to iterate through the html above .
This is my web scraping code to get the element :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,delay));

async function getTeams(url){


const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

await sleep(3000);

const games = await page.$x('//*[@id="main-one"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]');
//this is where I will execute the iteration part to get the matches with their scores 
await sleep(2000);


await browser.close();
}

getTeams('https://www.euroleague.net/main/results?gamenumber=28&phasetypecode=RS&seasoncode=E2019');
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me through the iteration part .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most accurate selector for a game box is `div.game.played` (a div which both has the `.game` and the `.played` CSS classes), you will need to count the elements that match this criteria. It is possible with [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) (`page .$$eval (selector, pageFunction[, ...args])`) which runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`.

As we are using the element indexes for the specific data fields we run a regular for loop with the length of the elements.

If you need a specific range of "euro_xyz" you can get the `data-code` attribute values in a [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) method with [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and check their number against the desired "xyz" number.

To collect each game's data we can define a collector array (`gameObj`) which can be extended with each iteration. In each iteration we fill an `actualGame` object with the actual data.

It is important to determine which [child elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) contain the corresponding data values, e.g.: the home club's name is `'div.game.played > a > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)'` the div child number selects the club while the span child number decides between the club name and the points. The loop's `[i]` index is responsible for grabbing the right game box's values (that's why it was counted in the beginning).

**For example:**

```js
const allGames = await page.$$('div.game.played')
const allGameLength = await page.$$eval('div.game.played', el => el.length)
const gameObj = []
for (let i = 0; i < allGameLength; i++) {
  try {
    let dataCode = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('data-code'), allGames[i])
    dataCode = parseInt(dataCode.replace('euro_', ''))

    if (dataCode > 243) {
      const actualGame = {
        homeClub: await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, (await page.$$('div.game.played > a > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)'))[i]),
        awayClub: await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, (await page.$$('div.game.played > a > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)'))[i]),
        homePoints: await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, (await page.$$('div.game.played > a > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)'))[i]),
        awayPoints: await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, (await page.$$('div.game.played > a > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2)'))[i]),
        gameDate: await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, (await page.$$('div.game.played > a > div:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1)'))[i])
      }
      gameObj.push(actualGame)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(gameObj))
```

There is a [`page.waitFor`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) method in puppeteer for the same purpose as your `sleep` function, but you can also wait for selectors to be appeared ([`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options)).